# What are my options for replicating a Postgresql database over an unreliable connection?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql database that I want to replicate in a master/slave configuration. But the slave is in a remote location with unreliable internet (as in it could go down at any time for seconds to days).
The nature of the application for which the database is being used means that if necessary updates can be postponed during long outs (and in fact since most of the updates would be done from the remote location that will happen most times simply as a side effect of the situation), so there wouldn't be millions of transactions to catch up on after a disconnect.
In addition, I would ideally be able to filter what gets replicated, as some tables of the database (notably the bits that tell the application about user permissions on that machine, which will differ on master or slave) need to be left intact or possibly only partially updated.
So far what I've read on replication doesn't seem to say much about recovery from connection failures and more importantly how to recover from them.
Is there a simple solution to this problem or am I going to have to do some coding?

Comment: This is going to be different for logical replication vs physical replication.  "I would ideally be able to filter what gets replicated" sounds like you will want logical replication, but do research that issue to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

> (and in fact since most of the updates would be done from the remote location that will happen most times simply as a side effect of the situation)

This makes me wonder if replication shouldn't be running the other way, with the master on the remote site and the replica on the main site.  What does the outpost do while the internet is down?  Does it cease operations, or continue doing things but save up transactions to be sent later?

Anyway, once replication is established, it should be pretty robust to occasional connection failures.  The main problem would be getting replication going in the first place, as seeding the replication in the easiest ways does assume an uninterrupted connection long enough to transfer the initial data.  An interrupted pg_basebackup for example cannot be resumed, but would have to be restarted from scratch.

One way to get replication seeded over a flaky connection is to run pg_basebackup over a LAN (e.g. on the master), compress the resulting backup, and transmit it using rsync (which can be resumed from an interruption with reasonable efficiency).  A different but analogous technique can be used for seeding logical replication.